# "Splash Page" NOT index.asp

Tags: javascript, html, css

Client requests a small video to play as a "splash page". But I dont want to make it the index page for SEO purposes. Can I place a re-direct line of code at the top of my index? Cookies to make it only once?

I think there might be a few ways to do this, but i know none of them.

Thanks for your time.
James

Comment: some cleverness with jquery could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like my comment you can use jquery to achieve this. Check my example: http://jsfiddle.net/LSjbS/

The splash section should come last in the markup, as it has the least importance.

Comment: Or alternatively if you want the splash screen to fade after a certain time, use this - [http://jsfiddle.net/JjvzT/](http://jsfiddle.net/JjvzT/)

Comment: Thanks Thats a great Idea, But What am I doing wrong here? http://www.kineticoriginsofrhythm.com/

Comment: you havent included jquery in your template, add this `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js'></script>` in the `<head>`

Comment: Add you'll need to add this to your style sheet `#container{display:none;}` check it out: [http://jsfiddle.net/kqKfK/14/](http://jsfiddle.net/kqKfK/14/)

Comment: Hey that Worked Great, Just cant get the Enter Button to work.

Comment: looks like you've chaged an id, change this line in the script `$("#container").attr('style','display:block');` to `$("#container-index").attr('style','display:block');` Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Varazi, just had a quick look at the site, and i looks like you've got it working. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout('Redirect()',4000); //time in ms
function Redirect()
{
  location.href = 'http://www.website.com/path/splash';
}

​
</script>
```

It's that easy :) Just put it in the head section. the 4000 is the time in ms (as shown by my comment) change this to 1 for an almost immediate redirect :)

Comment: Is a redirect a good idea? might the user get "worried" with the redirect? I was under the impression you shouldn't do this?

Comment: Yes, it's not such a good practice, but I though that's what you wanted :D Guess I was wrong. Another solution might be to use a videolightbox and diplay it automatically. But intro splash pages are awful in any case, is there any way to dissuade them? :D

Comment: I didn't ask the question ;) Im of the same opinion with splash screens. I also try to avoid redirects where possible.

Comment: Sorry, thought you were the OP. Splash screens should be _illegal_.

Comment: I [tweeted about this](http://twitter.com/ajthomascouk/status/38237813187022848) the other day.